# kerberos error when active-directory user connects to Solaris machine

Tags: active-directory, solaris, kerberos

I have configured two CentOS machines to authenticate via kerberos and LDAP to Windows Server 2008 R2 Active Directory.  I am now trying to do the same to a Solaris 10u9 (without upgrades to Kerberos or ldap) machine but am running into a problem -- active directory users cannot log in to the Solaris machine using ssh. Local users can log in fine. I can use `kinit` successfully and `id` works on active directory users. In /var/adm/messages I get this message every time I try to log in with an AD user (some information redacted):

```
Nov  3 16:31:03 hostname.f.q.d.n sshd[1024]: [ID 537602 auth.error] PAM-KRB5 (auth): krb5_verify_init_creds failed: Key table entry not found
```

However, the keytab is present and correct:

```
-bash-3.00$ ls -la /etc/krb5/krb5.keytab
-rwx------   1 root     root         422 Nov  3 15:33 /etc/krb5/krb5.keytab
-bash-3.00$ sudo klist -e -k /etc/krb5/krb5.keytab
Keytab name: WRFILE:/etc/krb5/krb5.keytab
KVNO Principal
---- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   3 HOST/hostname.f.q.d.n@F.Q.D.N (DES cbc mode with CRC-32)
   3 HOST/hostname.f.q.d.n@F.Q.D.N (DES cbc mode with RSA-MD5)
   3 HOST/hostname.f.q.d.n@F.Q.D.N (ArcFour with HMAC/md5)
   3 HOST/hostname.f.q.d.n@F.Q.D.N (AES-256 CTS mode with 96-bit SHA-1 HMAC)
   3 HOST/hostname.f.q.d.n@F.Q.D.N (AES-128 CTS mode with 96-bit SHA-1 HMAC)
-bash-3.00$
```

My hostname and domainname are also correct:

```
-bash-3.00$ hostname
hostname.f.q.d.n
-bash-3.00$ cat /etc/nodename
hostname.f.q.d.n
-bash-3.00$ domainname
f.q.d.n
-bash-3.00$ cat /etc/defaultdomain
f.q.d.n
```

All instances of f.q.d.n are equal. Same applies to F.Q.D.N and hostname.f.q.d.n. Any ideas why I am getting this message?

The same error occurs when a non-root user attempts to `su <AD-user>` on the machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solaris doesn't use MIT-Kerberos Packges, but a Sun-specific package that sometimes behaves a little different. You might want to try installing MIT-Kerberos to reuse your existing CentOS Config.